# Can a MacBook emulate a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, macbook

I have a TEAC AD800 with a USB outlet to record CDs or cassettes to a USB flash drive. Want to know if I can configure my MacBook so a USB port emulates a USB flash drive?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Those USB outputs on audio equipment like that are strictly to mount a USB flash drive so the device can write to it. Making a system “fake” being a USB flash drive is really not possible and a bad idea. Just go out and spend the $5 to $20 (US) it costs to buy a USB flash drive and that’s that.